# Laravel homestead symlinks not working on windows 10

Tags: vagrant, symlink, homestead, laravel-7

I have laravel homestead running on a windows 10 machine.

From an Admin CMD or Git Bash prompt when i run the following from the project root folder on local machine:

```
ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage
```

A storage directory is created but when i ssh into virtual machine it is highlighted as blue with a green background meaning its a normal directory and not a symlink - symlinks are highlighted as blue in ubuntu.

I know its not working because when I add a file into storage/app/public it does not appear in public/storage

Please note running vagrant ssh into project and running `php artisan storage:link` gives input/output error hence using the above method

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I encountered this too. in filesystems.php change the `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage` to `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/public`